# Highcharts (Highstocks) - clickable flag images

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

When adding flags to a chart, and using an image as the flag's shape, the outcome is not how I would expect. It seems that the clickable region of the flag is not actually where the image is placed - and also the text title is drawn off-centre.

[image: JSFiddle Screenshot]

For example, clicking towards the left of the image does not register the click. In this example, the click event will simply alert the flag's ID.

Below is the JavaScript object for the flag I'm trying to add:

```
{
    "type": "flags",
    "onSeries": "dataseries",
    "shadow": false,
    "width": 32,
    "shape": "url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)",
    "data": [{
        "x": 4,
        "title": "This is flag one",
        "text": "Click to edit",
        "id": "flag-01",
        "events": {
            "click": flagClick,
        },
    }],
}
```

Please could someone advise me how to rectify this issue? I have started some simple code of what I'm trying to achieve into JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/jR5kU/

Answer (score 0):

It's **a known issue which has been fixed** 4 days ago.
You can see it's report on the following link.
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1378#issuecomment-10885280